# Register every table/class from an app in the Django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an app named `doors` and my `models.py` for the app has 10 tables/class. Under my `admin.py`, how do I register every model in the file `models.py`?

For example, currently I have to hardcode it:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from doors.models import *

admin.site.register(Group)
admin.site.register(Item)
admin.site.register(ItemType)
admin.site.register(Location)
admin.site.register(Log)
admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(Property)
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Vendor)
```

Is there a way I perhaps find every class in `models.py` and loop through and register each class? Or is there some kind of wildcard I can use with Django?

Comment: Does this snippet do what you want: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2066/ ?

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the code helped a lot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out with @arie's link (for django < 1.8):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import get_models, get_app

for model in get_models(get_app('doors')):
    admin.site.register(model)
```

But I wonder if I can do this without `get_app`... Couldn't the code be smart enough to know the name of its own app?

Comment: On second thought, I realized this can be a bad idea since you can't register model twice. So use this code only if you don't need any customization to the models in the admin page (ie list views, filters, etc.).

Comment: To add to this, you can use this code and exclude specific models by name (i.e. models with customisations): for model in get_models(get_app('base')):
    if model.__name__ != 'Subscriber':
        admin.site.register(model)

Comment: @hobbes3 can't you unregister and register? At least at Django 1.7, not sure about '12 :)

Answer (score 50):

Seems get_models and get_app are no longer available in django 1.8.

The following can be used:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps

app = apps.get_app_config('dashboard')

for model_name, model in app.models.items():
    admin.site.register(model)
```

***EXTENSION***: If you would like to show all or select fields of the model as a grid instead of a single column unicode representation of the model objects you may use this:

```
app = apps.get_app_config('your_app_name')
for model_name, model in app.models.items():
    model_admin = type(model_name + "Admin", (admin.ModelAdmin,), {})

    model_admin.list_display = model.admin_list_display if hasattr(model, 'admin_list_display') else tuple([field.name for field in model._meta.fields])
    model_admin.list_filter = model.admin_list_filter if hasattr(model, 'admin_list_filter') else model_admin.list_display
    model_admin.list_display_links = model.admin_list_display_links if hasattr(model, 'admin_list_display_links') else ()
    model_admin.list_editable = model.admin_list_editable if hasattr(model, 'admin_list_editable') else ()
    model_admin.search_fields = model.admin_search_fields if hasattr(model, 'admin_search_fields') else ()

    admin.site.register(model, model_admin)
```

What this does is, it extends ModelAdmin class on the fly and sets the `list_display` field which is required for showing model data in grid representation in the admin. If you list your desired fields in your *model* as `admin_list_display` it takes that one, or generates a tuple of all fields available in the model, otherwise.

Other optional fields can similarly be set, such as `list_filter`.

See [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) for more info on list_display.

Answer (score 21):

From Django 1.7 on, you can use this code in your admin.py:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered

app_models = apps.get_app_config('my_app').get_models()
for model in app_models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Answer (score 9):

From Django 1.8, to fix the error message

```
RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.db.models.get_app is deprecated.
```

We can use this approach in 2 lines

```
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.models import *
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_app_config('my_app').models.values():
    admin.site.register(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered

 app_models = apps.get_app_config('app-name').get_models()
 for model in app_models:
     try:
         admin.site.register(model)
     except AlreadyRegistered:
         pass
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO, code only answers aren't voted up as quickly as answers that also describe what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Projects, ProjectsUsers, Comments, ProjectsDescription

Models = (Projects, ProjectsUsers, Comments, ProjectsDescription)

admin.site.register(Models)
```

Comment: Please can you explain your answer, rather than just dropping code?

Answer (score 0):

From Django3.0,you can try add the following code in admin.py

```
from . import models


class ListAdminMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        self.list_display = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if field.name != "id"]
        super(ListAdminMixin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)

for m in [your_model_name]:
    mod = getattr(models, m)
    admin_class = type('AdminClass', (ListAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin), {})
    try:
        admin.site.register(mod, admin_class)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```