# Why the `/admin/` only have few models?

Tags: python, django

I use the admin account login to the `/admin/`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Why there are only these field I can edit?
I have write tons models in my project. why do not show up?

Comment: Probably you have not registered them in admin.py?

Comment: You need to registered all those into admin.py file.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: These are default models. You have to register custom models to admin.py then only you can see them on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following code in your django app's admin.py file

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered

app_models = apps.get_app_config('my_app').get_models()
for model in app_models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/ and [Register every table/class from an app in the Django admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443863/register-every-table-class-from-an-app-in-the-django-admin-page)