# registering multiple models in Django Admin and excluding common field

Tags: django, django-admin

I am registering my (numerous) models using looping through apps.get_models() much like in the below answer:

[Register every table/class from an app in the Django admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443863/register-every-table-class-from-an-app-in-the-django-admin-page#answer-31184317)

My goal: as most of the models contain a common field that I would like to exclude from Django Admin I wonder if there is any way to do it without resorting to registering each model separately with exclude = FieldToBeExcluded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a common model admin class that every model uses

```
class CommonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['field_to_exclude']

for model in app_models:
    admin.site.register(model, CommonAdmin)
```